# Display one element per line with css and outer text

Tags: css

I have following html fragment:

```
<div>
    <a class="item" href="http://google.com">Google</a>,
    <a class="item" href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>,
    <a class="item" href="http://yandex.com">Yandex</a>
</div>
```

Right now it is displayed like this:

```
Google, Yahoo, Yandex
```

And I need it to be displayed like this:

```
Google,
Yahoo,
Yandex
```

Can it be done **ONLY by modifying CSS properties of .item class**? (without inserting new tags (e.g. BR) and without touching comma sign)?

I've tried with

```
.item {
    clear: both;
    float: left;    
}
```

But then all commas stay on the first line.

Comment: Nope. You'll have to use javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this can work,

add an empty string instead of adding a new comma in css and deleting or changing color of the old one

```
a:before {
    content:'';
    display: block; 
}
```

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dvTJ4/)**

Comment: VERY NICE.   I was trying to come up with something similar, but it wasn't clicking.   Seems to provide exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: It is really nice, but it don't solve my problem - I can't use pseudo-classes. Still, it is the best answer so far.

Comment: WOW! i could never come up witht his. So simple yet so complicated ^^

Comment: @miszczu Why would you NOT be able to use a pseudo-class?  You can change out the `a` with `.item` if you'd like, it will product the same results.

Comment: @Charlie74 The target tool in which I have this problem is not a simple web application. It is external app and I have very limited control on what I can modify in there. I'll save you the details on how that tool work and suck, we can't really do anything about that.

Comment: I've marked it as accepted cause this is the best answer and I really liked it, even so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma from the markup and do this

```
.item { display:block;}
.item:after {content:" ,"}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6F4s/2/

Comment: From the question *('without touching comma sign')* I would have thought the OP isn't able to remove the comma from the markup

Comment: I don't have control over commas and I can't remove them

Comment: I know it's not elegant but what about making the colour of the commas the same as the BG and doing what i suggested above ?

Comment: Well, I can't even change colour of the commas.

Answer (score 0):

What about put a comma with the `:after` selector as stated above:

```
.item:after 
{
    content:" ,"
}
```

Where you will hide any font that is outside the `.item` element:

```
#items
{
    font-size: 0;
}
```

And set the font-size to default again inside a `.item` element:

```
.item 
{
     font-size: medium;
     display:block;
}
```

And use the `display: block;` so that one item is set for each line.

and to remove the last comma:

```
.item:last-child:after
{
    content: "";
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6F4s/5/)

---

**Update**

When you can't define the parent element of the items you can do this with jQuery/javascript. Css does not support parent selection, so that's not possible:

```
$('.item').parent().css('font-size', '0');
```

### [jQuery example](http://jsfiddle.net/c6F4s/6/)

Comment: There is a comma after the last element which shouldn't be there. Also I can't modify properties of div#items. I've removed it in question.

Comment: What about selecting the parent element with jQuery?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use javascript

Comment: Haha. Well than it's simply not possible. Css uses HTML to markup different aspects. When you can't can go beyond item, you can never select the comma. The only way it would be selected is through the parent(which it is). When you can't acces this parent, you can't select the markup of the comma, thus not modify it. With the given code it's not possible :S

Comment: @nkmol take a look at the answer from `bhyuksel`.   Looks like he did it pretty simply...  it was a nice approach.

Comment: @Charlie74 Astonished... Thanks for telling me :)

Comment: @nkmol Agreed!  I was leaning towards the "can't be done" camp myself... and then there it was!  haha